# Trying to write a script that auto-clicks the buttons on a rating page. Script works for one single element but not the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, automation

I want to only click the + buttons on the page and make them increment to 4 for every table row (24 columns and 100 rows ).
The buttons only appear if you click on every single sector.
*[Complete Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdSRV.png)*

Thats how it looks when you click on it.
*[Picture of the button (+ button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxkVO.png)*

Thats a snippet of the code which I labeled.
*[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFGdQ.jpg)*

I used different scripts like this one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Hover over the checkbox to simulate a mouse-click.</p>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onmouseover="myFunction()" onclick="alert('click event occured')">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myCheck").click();
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

And tried to inser it at a logical point but it only works for one single table element.
I want the script to work on all +buttons.

Comment: Hello. I was wondering if someone could tell me what's wrong with this post so that I can edit and improve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select all the buttons with the class `skilllevel_inc` and then click 4 times on each of them. An example code would be :

```
let allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("skilllevel_inc");
for(var i=0 ; i<allButtons.length ; i++) {
   if(allButtons[i]) {
    let j=0;
    while(j<4) {
      allButtons[i].click();
      j+=1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try it out.

Comment: Np mate. Tell me if it works, if not we can try something else.